# Collaborative Mashup in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I need to implement a Google Maps collaborative project, but MyMaps is unsuitable as I need to restrict the participants' editorial rights to prevent them from editing each other's markers (which MyMaps allows).

So my questions are:

- Can Google Maps API (javascript v. 3) be used to construct a collaborative map?
- If so, can registered users have different editorial privileges?
- Can registered users be administered through Google Apps for the project domain?
- How technically demanding and time consuming would development of a basic collaborative map be?

Any advice appreciated!

Thanks